# Input in javascript from user handling

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to type and save data from a input field in a Modal. For some reason I cant type inside the field once I render the modal.

This is my code:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showHide : false,
            email: ' '
        }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.email]: e.target.value
        })
    }
```

This is where I attempted to have the user input.

```
<FormGroup>
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Email Adress:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name='email' placeholder="Email"
     value={this.state.email} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} >
</input>
</FormGroup>
```

Any ideas on why I cant type inside the the field? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the mistake is within your setState, you have to use e.target.name. This name property will provide a string value 'email' as set in input.

**Description:**

Name is an HTML attribute that is accessible from Event object being passed into the function, this name is set as 'email' in your input as you can see. And since you are not updating the state correctly, that input which is right now a controlled component (value bound to state) isn't being updated.

For more details look into ES6 computed names properties.

```
  this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
```

Comment: More about ES6 syntax is on https://reactdevstation.github.io/2020/03/18/es6-for-react.html

Comment: No problem, keep going :)